# Use the gamma prior to obtain the gamma posterior values

Tags: bayesian, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

I have the following information for the ages of individuals:

**Sample size = 5.**

Data: $$ x_i  = (10, 12, 15, 16, 14) $$

The **population mean** previously accurately estimated is 12.

Prior information shows the **standard deviation is 4** and the **range is from 2 to 5**.

**I also have the following information:**

Gamma prior:
$$ Gamma( \alpha, \beta ) $$
Mean: $$ \mu = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} $$
Variance: $$ Var = \frac{\alpha}{\beta^2} $$

Gamma posterior:
$$ Gamma(\alpha  + \frac{n}{2}, \beta  + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_{i} - \mu )^{2}}{2}) $$

**I'm supposed to use the gamma prior to obtain the gamma posterior. How can I do this with the information I have?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use poisson likelihood. For conjugate priors I usually look up the matching likelihood in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions).

### Posterior derivation for conjugate gamma prior

You do not speak about what is the meaning of your parameter. But I'll denote it $\lambda$, defined on $(0,\infty)$. The prior distribution.

$$\lambda\sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$$

Your data are discrete non-negative integers. If you are supposed to use conjugate prior, then you use Poisson likelihood.

$$x_i|\lambda\sim Po(\lambda)$$

Then, the posterior distribution is

$$\begin{align*}
P(\lambda|X)&\propto P(\lambda)\prod_iP(x_i|\lambda)\\
&\propto \lambda^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta\lambda}\prod_i\lambda^{x_i} e^{-\lambda} \\
&\propto \lambda^{\alpha+\sum_ix_i-1}e^{-\beta\lambda-\sum_i\lambda} \\
&=\lambda^{\alpha+nm-1}e^{-(\beta+n)\lambda} \\
&\propto Gamma(\alpha+nm, \beta+n)
\end{align*}
$$

Unfortunately, this does not fully match what you are supposed to end up with, but it is close.